# How to resolve this: [WARN] shiny-server - Failed to delete log file /var/log/shiny-server/file.log

Tags: r, docker, shiny, google-cloud-run

I am deploying a docker container using Google Cloud Run. The docker container contains a R shiny app. And after a while from viewing the app, I see in the Cloud Run logs, the following:

```
[WARN] shiny-server - Failed to delete log file /var/log/shiny-server/shiny-server-xxx.log: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '/var/log/shiny-server/shiny-server-xxx.log'
```

I want it to be able to delete the old log so it doesn't pile up in the container, and
stop this warning to occur. How do I accomplish this? Is it a permissions error? I tried looking up solutions for this, but I don't even see someone complaining about this error. Why am I getting this then? What does it mean by "unlink" the log file? Please tell me what I am missing to allow log files to be removed/deleted. Thank you for any info you can give me.

In **/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh**, the first few lines contain:

```
# Make sure the directory for individual app logs exists
mkdir -p /var/log/shiny-server
chown shiny.shiny /var/log/shiny-server
```

My **etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf** is the original file (I have not changed it in any way):

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

In my **Dockerfile**, I have:

```
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
EXPOSE 3838

RUN sudo chown -R shiny:shiny /srv/shiny-server
USER shiny

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

Note: the line with "USER shiny" helped to remove the warning in the logs stating that the app should be run as non-root.

==============================

**UPDATE**

I've changed my **/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh** file to be:

```
mkdir -p /var/log/shiny-server
chown -R shiny:shiny /var/log/shiny-server
```

But I am still seeing the log:

```
[WARN] shiny-server - Failed to delete log file /var/log/shiny-server/shiny-server-shiny-20210831-133933-46421.log: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '/var/log/shiny-server/shiny-server-shiny-20210831-133933-46421.log'
```

This is what the current permissions look like on the /var/log/shiny-server folder:
[image: what the current permissions look like on /var/log/shiny-server folder]

And this, although not the exact same log file as stated in the error, is the permissions on the log file itself in /var/log/shiny-server:
[image]

Shouldn't this be enough permissions to allow the shiny user to delete the log file?

Comment: Log files are deleted on its own when Cloud Run downscales (shutdown) an instance. If your service is constantly running and you worry that it'll fill up your memory fast, then it'd be better to write logs using standard output and standard error. See this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#container-logs) as reference.

Comment: thank you @Dondi. i think that helps me out. I was just worried that these log files in the container were going to take up all the space eventually. but I do see the container shutting down with no activity. if that means the log files will be deleted, then Im good with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for the answer to my post, I basically left it alone and ignore those warnings. Based on [@Dondi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7031308/dondi)'s comment, the logs shouldn't use up all the space allocated to my container since it will shutdown the instance when it sits idle. Plus the shiny logs are automatically written to stdout (I'm using rocker/shiny as my base image) so I won't lose any of the logs written by the shiny app.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh`. To change ownership recursively on all files and directories on a given directory, you should use -R option. Additionally, when changing ownership for both user and group in a single command, you should use a **colon**.

In **/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh** try this:

```
chown -R shiny:shiny /var/log/shiny-server
```

Check this [document](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-chown-command/#how-to-recursively-change-the-file-ownership) for chown command reference.

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried out your changes, but I still see that "failed to delete log file" warning in my logs. I've updated the original post to show what I changed and what the current permissions look like on the folder /var/log/shiny-server.